# How to pass an object type to call a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

My generic method is this

```
public static class AppContainerInstaller
{
    public static IMessageHandler<T> Resolve<T>() 
    {
        return _container.Resolve<IMessageHandler<T>>();
    }
}
```

I am trying to call this generic method from a different class

```
public static string ProcessMessage(IMessage message)
{
    messageHandler = AppContainerInstaller.Resolve<message.GetType()>();
    // THe previous line throws an error.
    return messageHandler.Handle(message);
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to pass the type of message to a generic method?

Comment: The generic type needs to known at compile time (Resolve<IMessage>).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to get the runtime type: pass the message as a parameter or use reflection.

Modifying the method:

```
public static IMessageHandler<T> Resolve<T>(T unused) 
{
    return _container.Resolve<IMessageHandler<T>>();
}
```

Which will allow runtime type lookup:

```
// Cast to dynamic to force runtime type
messageHandler = AppContainerInstaller.Resolve((dynamic) message);
```

You can also to use reflection although there is a performance penalty.

```
private static readonly MethodInfo ResolveMethodInfo
    = typeof(AppContainerInstaller).GetMethod("Resolve", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

// Assuming there exists a non-generic interface IMessageHandler
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<IMessageHandler>> _methodCache
    = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<IMessageHandler>>();

public static string ProcessMessage(IMessage message)
{
    messageHandler = Resolve(message.GetType());
    return messageHandler.Handle(message);
}

private IMessageHandler Resolve(Type type)
{
    // Cache the generated method to avoid repeated reflection penalty.
    var resolve = _methodCache.GetOrAdd(type, () => ResolveMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type));
    return resolve();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to do this:

```
messageHandler = AppContainerInstaller.Resolve<IMessage>();
```

`Resolve` method is the one who should get the type being passed in T. You see, when using generics, you must provide an actual type.And you probably want to change `Resolve` to get a T parameter, so you can pass `message`. Something like this:

```
public static IMessageHandler<T> Resolve<T>(T param)
```

and you call it like this:

```
messageHandler = AppContainerInstaller.Resolve<IMessage>(message);
```